# get token display name from metamask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask

I am connecting to my wallet in metamask. I have the following code in my frontend code

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any")
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
const signer = provider.getSigner()
const address = await signer.getAddress()
const balance = await signer.getBalance()
```

That works all great. So I can get the address of the wallet and I also get the balance, but I couldn't figure out how to get the token name like BTC, USDT, ...

I also couldn't find something useful in the official documentation for the provider https://docs.ethers.io/v3/api-providers.html

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I couldn't figure out how to get the token name like BTC, USDT, ...

Because you don't.

You need to provide a token name - address mappings yourself, or ask from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a chainId, like this

```
const { chainId } = await provider.getNetwork()
```

And then define a mapping of chain ids to coin display names, like this:

```
const mapping = { 1: 'eth', 137: 'matic', ... }
// use https://chainlist.org/ to get the data
```

Or, you can look for some API to get the network data given the chainId of it